# Painting in 3D window shows up on the other side of my model from where I paint

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, texture-painting

I've been having trouble getting the texture painting to work right.

My problem is when I paint directly on my model in the 3D view the paint stroke goes to the back of where I painted, like if I paint of his chest it shows up on his back, if I paint on his face it shows up on the back of his head.

All my painting down within the UV window shows up in the correct places, though.

I haven't been able to figure out what is causing this problem.  I'm wondering if I have a setting that is off that I don't know about or if something is off with my model. I've tried exporting my model and making new scenes with the export and each one has had a problem with painting.

Comment: Try to recalculate the normals

Comment: How do I ensure the normals are facing the correct way?

Comment: Okay so, It was indeed a normal problem. My normals work backwards.

Comment: I have to say, it was obvious in 2.7, in 2.8 it's not but I must be missing something, anyway in Edit mode you can activate a Face Orientation option in the Display Overlays options, and you can see that the mesh is completely red, so it's indeed the normals that you need to flip with a select all and shift N

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I had no idea how to even check what my normals looked like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a *Normals* issue, in 2.8, in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom normals and you don't want to recalculate them- select the faces that are painting on the back and Flip the normals for them. You can find that opinion under *Mesh > Normals > Flip*. Turn on *Face Orientation* in the *Viewport Overlays* to see which faces need flipped. Red faces are inverted, and will paint on the back