# how can I sync the object in the texture paint?

Tags: texture-painting

I am beginner in blender ,
according to my totural , I have to sync the object in the texture paint but I can not do this.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, iam not sure what you mean by sync. To use paint you need to have some UVs for that donut and assign a texture to the material to be able to paint on it.

Comment: hi :) I want to paint the donut in the texture paint. but the donut is not syncing.I mean this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=541&v=nht2RoYBUfA&feature=emb_logo

thank you:)

Comment: I have no idea what you have done :D but the sync is just make the texture the base color to make the connection, what you already have, according to your nodes. Your model doesn't even want to change materials. I just duplicated the donut and delete the original and everything worked.

Comment: @Fowl. I had  problem with the connection yes! maybe I have found the problem and that was my mistake:) I copied my donut three times and they are inside of their the solution is to delete the copied donut:D thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing my story in case someone else comes here with the same scenario as me. My image texture was out of sync with what I painted. I then realized that every stroke I was making was appearing on the opposite side of my object and I had the normals issue described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144421/painting-in-3d-window-shows-up-on-the-other-side-of-my-model-from-where-i-paint). By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in *Edit mode*, that recalculated the normals and solved the problem.